# Is there a maximum number of streams in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

Is there a maximum number of streams that can be created in CUDA?

To clarify I mean CUDA streams as in the stream that allows you to execute kernels and memory operations.

Comment: Do you mean CUDA streams (witch provide parallel memory operations and kernel executions) or CUDA threads (to execute single kernel).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I haven't seen a limit in any documentation, but that doesn't mean all streams will execute concurrently, since that is a hard hardware limit (Multiprocessors, registers, etc).

Answer (score 26):

There is no realistic limit to the number of streams you can create (at least 1000's).  However, there's a limit to the number of streams you can use effectively to achieve concurrency.

In Fermi, the architecture supports 16-way concurrent kernel launches, but there is only a single connection from the host to the GPU.  So even if you have 16 CUDA streams, they'll eventually get funneled into one HW queue.  This can create false data-dependencies, and limit the amount of concurrency one can easily get.

With Kepler, the number of connections between the Host and the GPU is now 32 (instead of one with Fermi). With the new Hyper-Q technology, it is now much easier to keep the GPU busy with concurrent work.

Comment: You might want to mention the overhead of creating and destroying streams, which will have an effect if many streams are created and destroyed.

Comment: @Mark Ebersole  But why we needed 32 connections between the Host and the GPU for the only 16-way concurrent kernel launches of Streams on Kepler?

Comment: There is only one default stream, AFAIK: stream 0 (AKA the "null stream"). If you mean with "default stream per thread" option, it's one per host thread.

Comment: This answer is in dire need for an update (I can't edit it right now). CC 7.5 - 9.0 (Turing, Ampere, Ada and Hopper) all support up to 128 concurrent launches. For more information see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications) (second table, first entry).

Answer (score 13):

According to this NVIDIA presentation, max is 16 streams (on Fermi).
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf

To clarify, I've successfully created more than 16 streams, but I think the hardware can only support 16 concurrent kernels, so the excess ones are wasted in terms of concurrency.

Kepler is probably different.